# How to setup font-awesome with a single-spa project?

Tags: font-awesome, single-spa

I have a single spa application with a root-config, a styleguide, and a couple of react applications. All of these application are generated using the `yarn create single-spa` command.

I tried creating a `kit` from the font-awesome website and adding it to the root-config index.ejs inside the `head` tag.

Then I tried adding `<i className='fa-brands fa-facebook-f' />` in one of my MFEs.
The loaded index.html in my browser include the tag code. But it's dimensions are 0x0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some styles.

When you generate your `kit`, the font awesome website shares a snippet of the `script` tag for your kit.
You need to place it in the `head` section of your `root-config`.
But that's not all. You also need to add some `font-faces`.

The same page (with the snippet) also has a link to download example html file.
If you check that file it has extra `style` tags.
Once you add those to your `root-config`, the icons will start showing up.

This issue is not single-spa, it's the confusing documentation for font-awesome.